# SSRS 2012- Avoid render a report when there are no rows to return

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am wondering if there is any possible way to prevent a report to execute or run when there are no rows that can be returned in SQL Server Reporting Services 2012. in other words, there are no rows in the DB to be returned.

We're are trying to reduce the amount of E-mails sent out by preventing reports from run when there are nothing to show.

Thanks a bunch

Marcus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often this is accomplished by using ["Data Driven Subscriptions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx) but this feature is only available in certain SQL editions: Enterprise and Business Intelligence, but not in Standard.

So there are a number of creative workarounds. But I don't like any of them, and all require a fair bit of work outside of SSRS.

The workarounds I've seen include: Creating the Subscription and then disabling or enabling the SQL job that sends the subscription (identified by Guid.)

Create a .NET wrapper .exe to handle sending the email. It can run the query first to see how many rows are returned, and then if needed, generate the report and include it in an email.